# Why is it that my input filter isnt working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created some input filters with jQuery Datatables but isnt working. The fact is that i get no errors while inspecting the console and i have no clue what is happening.

This is my view:

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-responsive" width="100%">
                        <thead class="thead">
                            <tr>
                                <th style="display: none">Codigo</th>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Producto</th>
                                <th>Tipo de Producto</th>
                                <th>Marca</th>
                                <th>Modelo</th>
                                <th>Moneda</th>
                                <th>Descripcion</th>
                                
                                <th>Costo</th>
                                
                                <th style="width: 12%">Accion</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           
                            @foreach($file as $key => $product)
                            @if($product->status == 1)
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="display: none">{{ $key+1 }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{$product->marca->brandName . " " . $product->modelo->modelName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product['ptype']['productType']}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->marca->brandName }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->modelo->modelName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->coin }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->description }}</td>
                                    
                                    <td>{{ $product->cost }}</td>
                                    
                                    @php
                                    $count_product = App\Model\Purchase::where('product_id',$product->id)->count();
                                    @endphp
                                        <td>


                                        <!--<a title="Download" id="download" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"
                                            href="/products/download/{{ $product->file }}"><i
                                                class="fa fa-download"></i></a>-->
                                        <a title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm text-white"
                                            style="background-image: linear-gradient(200deg, #070525ce 1%, rgb(1, 0, 5)100%);"
                                            href="{{ route('products.edit', $product->id) }}"><i
                                                class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                        <a title="Delete" id="delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                                            href="{{ route('products.delete', $product->id) }}"><i
                                                class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                                        <a title="Info" id="info" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-idUpdate="'.$product->id.'" data-target="#ProductView"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endif

                                
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>

<tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control filter-input" placeholder="Buscar por id..." data-column="0">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control filter-input" placeholder="Buscar por marca..." data-column="1">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control filter-input" placeholder="Buscar por modelo..." data-column="2">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
```

And this is my script:

```
@section('javascripts')

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#example1').Datatable({
            'processing': true,
            'serverSide': true,
            'ajax': "{{ route('products.view') }}",
            'columns': [
                {'data': 'id'},
                {'data': 'brandName'},
                {'data': 'modelName'}
            ],
        });

        $('.filter-input').keyup(function() {
            table.column( $(this).data('column'))
                .search( $(this).val())
                .draw();
        });

        
    })
</script>

@endsection
```

Does anybody knows what is happening? Because it is a simple input search and it seems as if it doesnt identifies my columns nor what im inputing.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#example1').Datatable({
            'processing': true,
            'serverSide': true,
            'ajax': "{{ route('products.view') }}",
            'columns': [
                {'data': 'id'},
                {'data': 'brandName'},
                {'data': 'modelName'}
            ],
        });

        $('.filter-input').keyup(function() {
            table.column( $(this).data('column'))
                .search( $(this).val())
                .draw();
        });

        
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-responsive" width="100%">
                            <thead class="thead">
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="display: none">Codigo</th>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Producto</th>
                                    <th>Tipo de Producto</th>
                                    <th>Marca</th>
                                    <th>Modelo</th>
                                    <th>Moneda</th>
                                    <th>Descripcion</th>
                                    
                                    <th>Costo</th>
                                    
                                    <th style="width: 12%">Accion</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                               
                                @foreach($file as $key => $product)
                                @if($product->status == 1)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="display: none">{{ $key+1 }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
                                        <td>{{$product->marca->brandName . " " . $product->modelo->modelName}}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $product['ptype']['productType']}}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $product->marca->brandName }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $product->modelo->modelName}}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $product->coin }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $product->description }}</td>
                                        
                                        <td>{{ $product->cost }}</td>
                                        
                                        @php
                                        $count_product = App\Model\Purchase::where('product_id',$product->id)->count();
                                        @endphp
                                            <td>


                                            <!--<a title="Download" id="download" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"
                                                href="/products/download/{{ $product->file }}"><i
                                                    class="fa fa-download"></i></a>-->
                                            <a title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm text-white"
                                                style="background-image: linear-gradient(200deg, #070525ce 1%, rgb(1, 0, 5)100%);"
                                                href="{{ route('products.edit', $product->id) }}"><i
                                                    class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                            <a title="Delete" id="delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                                                href="{{ route('products.delete', $product->id) }}"><i
                                                    class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                                            <a title="Info" id="info" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-idUpdate="'.$product->id.'" data-target="#ProductView"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endif

                                    
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control filter-input" placeholder="Buscar por id..." data-column="0">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control filter-input" placeholder="Buscar por marca..." data-column="1">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control filter-input" placeholder="Buscar por modelo..." data-column="2">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div><!-- /.card-body -->
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what the intended result it, and how it is currently acting.

Comment: you should highlight your problem and not posting full code for us to find

Comment: You posted your template. But I would be more interested to see what your browser received. Can you create a snippet here that reproduces the problem? Thanks!

Comment: @LajosArpad i added the snippet but it wont recognice my laravel data

Comment: @AmirRahman believe me i did not, i just pasted my table with each column and the data im passing to each one of them, and my script where im trying to filter by each column as i input any character.

Comment: @DBS im trying to filter by column of my datatable, using input filters but nothing is happening. And im not getting any errors from the console.

Comment: @matuco1998 this is not a Laravel question. Put in some dummy data instead of your actual Laravel data. We are interested in your Javascript's behavior.